# How to retrieve document or Video file extension from SharePoint library using COM JavaScript

Tags: file-upload, video, com

How to retrieve document or Video  file  extension from SharePoint library using COM JavaScript

but i Tried this code but Error will be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        {
             LoadZipCodes();
             alert("Ftc");
        });

function LoadZipCodes()
    {
        $.ajax({ ///MyLearning/My%20Learning%20Videos/HaysLMS?Web=1
                url:"http://vm-srv-hays:2015/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'/My Learning Videos/Hays-SP2013/')/files",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success : function(data){ //data will have the video object
                //var name = data.d.results[0].Name;
                //console.log(title); 
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error : function(args) {
                console.log(args);
                }});

}
```

[image]

Comment: You are retrieving this from an asset library or a document library? And please elaborate your question more. Details on what you have done, where you are retrieving from will be helpful.

Comment: I want to retrieving from asset library.

Comment: i retried file name but , I need file name with their Extension, **Example Video.mp4,**

Comment: This is not an error. It's the JSON string that you're alerting. Looking at that, no data is being returned. Make sure your server relative url is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a video (Content type: Video) is stored in the asset library, they are stored as folders with folder name being the video name. What you are getting is only the name of the folder. The properties (URL, full name) and the video itself are stored within the folder as another content type known as Video Rendition. Getting the actual video can be done using REST api with the following url:

`http://siteurl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Video Name')/Files`.

**Update:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://siteUrl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'/AssetLibName/VideoName\')/files',
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success : function(data){ //data will have the video object
        var name = data.d.results[0].Name;
        console.log(title); 
    },
    error : function(args) {
        console.log(args);
    }
});
```

Note: Server Relative URL will change based on where the video is stored i.e. location of site collection / subsite.

Comment: Thank you ! can you show me the full code ? its will be helpful for me

Comment: I try this code 'url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Hays-SP2013')/Files.' Error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @SNGOKUL check updated answer.

Comment: @SNGOKUL I noticed you unmarked it as answer. Let me know what is not working in this so I can help you.

Comment: I tried this code

Comment: And that is similar to my code? :)

Comment: ya. but i need Video file extension on that **alert(JSON.stringify(data));**

Comment: what if i want to file with any extension?actually i tried same approach where I want to fetch file name with extension,that i am not able get it

Comment: @Ma6139735 what do you get when you access `http://siteurl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Video Name')/Files`? You should get all video files.

Comment: actually i dont want to get only video file,here i want to get any file name but with file extension like abc.png n i am getting abc only

Comment: You are getting the folder under which all video files are stored. You have to append `/Files` to the video to get all these files.